# How to Make multiple TinyMCE frames simultaneously work

Tags: tinymce, wysiwyg

i have 5 pages that use tinyMCE, all of them are in iframe but just one them works out.

how can i solve this problem ?

[image]

the init code is:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    // General options
    mode: "exact",
    theme: "advanced",
    elements: "txtBody",
    dialog_type: "modal",
    width: "500",
    height: "400",
    plugins: "autolink,lists,table,advhr,media,searchreplace,contextmenu,paste,directionality,noneditable,xhtmlxtras,template",
    theme_advanced_buttons1: "styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,",
    theme_advanced_buttons2: "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,search,replace,insertfile,insertimage,",
    theme_advanced_buttons3: "undo,redo,link,unlink,image,cleanup,code,forecolor,backcolortablecontrols,removeformat,sub,sup,media,advhr,ltr,rtl",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "right",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing: true,
    skin: "o2k7",
    skin_variant: "silver",
    content_css: "../../App_Themes/Document.css"
});
```

Comment: Can describe some more about what you are doing and how you include TinyMCE on the pages. Also, I assume you have the same id for all of the text areas (that is, "txtBody")

Comment: tnx all, problem was solved by changing parent div position from relative/absolute to fix

Answer (score 0):

The most logical explanation is that you're only specifying one of them with your elements option. But please provide more detail if that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

```
theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
theme_advanced_resizing : true,
theme_advanced_resizing_min_height : 100,
```

try above in your code toolbar alignment is 'right' instead of 'left'

Answer (score 0):

Eighter you need to specify all [elements](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3aelements) (ids of your html elments which should be turned into an editor instance) when using `mode: 'exact,'`:

```
elements: 'my_html_element_id1,my_html_element_id2,my_html_element_id3,my_html_element_id,my_html_element_id5',
```

or you use `mode: "textareas",` and take care that there are exactly 5 textareas on your page and with **different** IDs.

There are also other possible settings. You might check them out having a lokk at the tinymce documentation concerning [the mode setting](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3amode).